ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC : encoding issue in js files
I created ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC web app. I have language config file for datatables like this:
var tr_lang = {
    "emptyTable": "Tabloda herhangi bir veri mevcut değil",
    "info": "_TOTAL_ kayıttan _START_ - _END_ arasındaki kayıtlar gösteriliyor",
    ...
}

On the client side and developer tools, I see this file as below
   var tr_lang = {
       "emptyTable": "Tabloda herhangi bir veri mevcut de�il",
       "info": "_TOTAL_ kay�ttan _START_ - _END_ aras�ndaki kay�tlar g�steriliyor",
   }

And one of my script file there is line like this.
console.log("Parametre Kategori kayıt");

In client side I see result as
Parametre Kategori kay�t

There is a encoding problem with Turkish characters. How can I solve this?
P.S. : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.6

Ensure all your files are saved as UTF-8. This doesn't have anything to do with ASP.NET Core unless your JS files are being re-encoded by ASP.NET Core somehow?

I try to understand problem if i use console.log("Kayıt") in .cshtml file (View) directly between 
Unfortunately this is not related with font. I tried to write same words in same font family in cshtml directly there was no problem. The .js files has no problem in developmen environment. But if i reach this file from Developer Console > Sources > testFile.js the characters also corrupted in there. I guess problem start in server side. This is the first time i use .net 8.0 framework. I didn't face this issue before in previous frameworks.

But maybe the problem may be related to visual studio itself rather than .net core, I am now considering this possibility.

@BK52 the problem is that the file wasn't saved as UTF8. This isn't about fonts, it's about how the actual file was save. When you see � it always means that text was stored using the wrong codepage. The character � is called the Replacement Character, used when there's no way to write or read a character with a non-Unicode codepage

I solved the problem.
The problem was with Visual Studio itself rather than ASP.NET Core 8.0. Select the Encoding option in "Advanced Save Options" under the "File" menu.
I translated it to Turkish (Windows) - Codapage 1254 -> Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001.
If you don't see the "Advanced Save Options" option under the "File" menu, take a look at this.

That's what Dai said in the first comment. The character � always appears when the wrong non-Unicode page was used.

You should probably check: What is the default encoding for source files in Visual Studio 2017?. Code files should be saved as UTF8 automatically.  You can also set the default encoding through an .editorconfig file

@PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your interest. I thought the problem was caused by the new framework, but later I realized that the editor version was also updated. Then I solved my problem by following the steps above.

You'd have the same problem with any text editor if you saved the file with the wrong encoding. This isn't about a "new" VS version. In the past VS always stored source files using the local encoding. It's newer versions that automatically save to UTF8. You shouldn't have encountered this problem unless there's either a bug or the file was copied from another or older project, that used 1254 instead of UTF8
